# Tableview not populating automatically from initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to populate the deletePartTableview when the screen is loaded. The data is present but the table is not populating. The addPartTableView on the same screen behaves as expected.

I'm not sure what else to try.

```java
Stage stage;
Parent scene;

@FXML
private TextField searchProducttxt;

@FXML
private TextField productIdtxt;

@FXML
private TextField productNametxt;

@FXML
private TextField invtxt;

@FXML
private TextField pricetxt;

@FXML
private TextField maxtxt;

@FXML
private TextField mintxt;

@FXML
private TableView<Part> addPartTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Integer> partIdAddTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, String> partNameAddTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Integer> invAddTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Double> priceAddTableCol;

@FXML
private TableView<Part> deletePartTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Integer> partIdDeleteTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, String> partNameDeleteTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Integer> invDeleteTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Part, Double> priceDeletetableCol;

private ObservableList<Part> currentlySelectedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void sendProduct(Product product) {
    productIdtxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getId()));
    productNametxt.setText(product.getName());
    pricetxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
    invtxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getStock()));
    maxtxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getMax()));
    mintxt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getMin()));
}

@FXML
void onActionAddPart(ActionEvent event) {
    Product productX = Inventory.lookupProductStringId(productIdtxt.getText());
    if (productX.getAllAssociatedParts().contains(addPartTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()) == true) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "This part has already been added");
        alert.setTitle("Duplicate Part");
        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {
        productX.addAssociatedPart(addPartTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        deletePartTableView.setItems(productX.getAllAssociatedParts());
    }
}

@FXML
void onActionCancel(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to cancel?");
    alert.setTitle("Cancel");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(scene));
        stage.show();
    }
}

@FXML
void onActionDeletePart(ActionEvent event) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {

    }
}

@FXML
void onActionSavePart(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    String productId = productIdtxt.getText();
    String productName = productNametxt.getText();
    String productInv = invtxt.getText();
    String productPrice = pricetxt.getText();
    String productMin = mintxt.getText();
    String productMax = maxtxt.getText();
    Product productX = Inventory.lookupProductStringId(productIdtxt.getText());
    if (Integer.parseInt(productInv) >= Integer.parseInt(productMin) && Integer.parseInt(productInv) <= Integer.parseInt(productMax)) {

        Product modProduct = new Product(Integer.parseInt(productId), productName, Double.parseDouble(productPrice), Integer.parseInt(productInv), Integer.parseInt(productMin), Integer.parseInt(productMax));

        modProduct.setAssociatedParts(productX.getAllAssociatedParts());

        Inventory.updateProduct(modProduct.getId(), modProduct);

        stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(scene));
        stage.show();
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Inventory Alert");
        alert.setContentText("Inventory is set below minimum or above maximum stock level. Please try again.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}

@FXML
void onActionSearchProducts(ActionEvent event) {
    String partSearchInput = searchProducttxt.getText();
    addPartTableView.getSelectionModel().select(Inventory.lookupPartNameOrId(partSearchInput));
}

public void setCurrentlySelectedParts(ObservableList<Part> parts) {
    this.currentlySelectedParts = parts;
}

public void addCurrentlySelectedPart(Part part) {
    currentlySelectedParts.add(part);
}

public void deleteCurrentlySelectedPart(Part part) {
    currentlySelectedParts.remove(part);
}

public ObservableList<Part> getAllCurrentlySelectedParts() {
    return currentlySelectedParts;
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    addPartTableView.setItems(Inventory.getAllParts());
    partIdAddTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    partNameAddTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    invAddTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));
    priceAddTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

    Product productX = Inventory.lookupProductStringId(productIdtxt.getText());
    deletePartTableView.setItems(productX.getAllAssociatedParts());
    partIdDeleteTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    partNameDeleteTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    invDeleteTableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));
    priceDeletetableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
}

public void updateAddPartsTableView() {
    addPartTableView.setItems(Inventory.getAllParts());
}

public void updateDeletePartsTableView() {
    Product productX = Inventory.lookupProductStringId(productIdtxt.getText());
    deletePartTableView.setItems(productX.getAllAssociatedParts());
}


/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
```

The expected result is that, when loading, the deletePartTableview should populate with the items from the associatedParts observableList. Instead, the table is not populating when loading despite the data being there.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That said: frequent errors are mis-spelling of property names (don't use PropertyValueFactory, let your model expose properties and use them instead) or not populating the instance of tableView that you think you are populating or some logic error. Strip it down to find the difference between the table that's populated and the one that's not

Comment: It seems weird that you use the content of a `TextField` at initialisation to retrieve some data. Most likely the field contains the empty string which can easily be hardcoded without the need to retrieve the value of a `TextField`. (`Inventory.lookupProductStringId(productIdtxt.getText())`)

Comment: @kleopatra I don't understand the following sentence from your comment. Can you elaborate? _let your model expose properties and use them instead_

Comment: @Abra propertyValueFactory accesses the getters/setters reflectively by the passed-in string (assuming they follow java been naming conventions) - that's prone to spelling/typing mistakes and only bubble up at runtime. If you let the model expose a property, you can pass that property from a cellValueFactory which is checked at compile time